# JavaScript form validation isn't checking for errors

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I have this JavaScript code in the head portion of a php file:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function validateFirstName(field)
        {
            if (field == "")
            {
                return "Please enter a first name.\n";
            }
            else if (/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(field))
            {
                return "Invalid first name.\n";
            }
            return "";
        }
        function validateLastName(field)
        {
            if (field == "")
            {
                return "Please enter a last name.\n";
            }
            else if (/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(field))
            {
                return "Invalid last name.\n";
            }
            return "";
        }
        //more functions eliminated
        function validate(form)
        {
            fail = validateFirstName(form.firstname.value);
            fail += validateLastName(form.lastname.value);
            //and so forth

            if (fail == "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                alert(fail);
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And the form:

```
<form action="StudentSignUpPageAddingData.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    <p id="p3">First Name: <input id="roundedcorners" type="text" name="firstname"><br></p>
    <p id="p3">Last Name: <input id="roundedcorners" type="text" name="lastname"><br></p>
//and so forth
    <input id="i1" type="submit" value="Done!">
</form>
```

When I run it, though, the program skips to the code in StudentSignUpPageAddingData.php. I'm new to PHP and JavaScript, so I'm wondering if there's a problem with the onsubmit call. Should I also consider pasting the JavaScript code in a separate file and simply referencing it in the PHP file?

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3pwugjyx/. Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Is all of your code in the same php file? If not, your javascript should be in (or included in) the same document as the form.

Comment: Why do you have the same `id` on both fields?... they should be unique.  Also, if it's called `roundedcorners`, that seems more like it should be a `class` than an `id`.

Comment: Sorry about the ids. I'll get them changed to unique names soon.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it turns out JavaScript was disabled for some reason on my computer. Here's a quick link to figure out how to quickly enable JavaScript:

http://activatejavascript.org/en/instructions/safari